# Python tkinter change default entry widget background color

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter-entry

Python tkinter change default entry widget background color

I am trying to change the default background colour for the "Entry" widget without success. Below is the code I have and none of them work. How do I make it work?

Environment: Python 3.10.0 Windows 21H1

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

objWindow = objTK.Tk()
objStyle = objTTK.Style()
objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.map("TEntry", background=[("readonly", "blue")], \
                    fieldbackground=[("readonly", "blue")], \
                    disabledbackground=[("readonly", "blue")])

objEntry = objTK.Entry(master=objWindow, width=10)
objEntry.place(x=10, y=10)
objEntry.insert(0, "Test")
objEntry.config(state="readonly")

objWindow.geometry("100x100")

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda _: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have find it yourself by now but just for the ones searching the answer.

To work the Entry must be a **ttk**.Entry not a **tk**.Entry
just change to

```
objEntry = objTTK.Entry(master=objWindow, width=10)
```